# When configuring my ODBC driver from MySql, I get the error "Architecture Mismatch"

Tags: mysql

When configuring my ODBC driver from MySql, I get the error "Architecture Mismatch between the Driver and Application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a 64-bit version of Windows 7?

The problem occurs with version 5.1.10 of the connector. Not sure about 5.1.9.

However, version 5.1.8 works. You can find it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) under "Archives".

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the appropiate version (32-bit or 64-bit) for the version of your application.